# YouTube API v3 load last videos from the playlist

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a problem with the new YouTube API . with version 2 via an ajax call I could take the last video uploaded to a playlist , how can I do with the new API ? thanks for your support .

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answer , I tried the code but returns a javascript error : **"Can not read property 'setApiKey' of undefined"** below the html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>YouTube</title>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>

    <script>    
        gapi.client.setApiKey('{API-KEY-HERE}');
        gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function () {

            var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
                part: 'snippet',
                playlistId: 'PLTK1i0pncVu_tLhgrPo_o7QcRocqozxUv'
            });

            request.execute(function (response) {
                response.items.sort(function(a,b) {return a.snippet.publishedAt < b.snippet.publishedAt})

                for (var i=0; i<response.items.length;i++)
                {
                    console.log(response.items[i].snippet.title + " published at " + response.items[i].snippet.publishedAt)
                }
            });
        });
    </script>   


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would load all the videos for a specified playlist and order them by `publishedAt`. For the latest video just take the first result.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>YouTube</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script>
        var allVideos = new Array();

        function onGoogleLoad() {
            gapi.client.setApiKey('{YOUR-API-KEY}');
            gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {

                GatherVideos("", function() {

                    allVideos.sort(function(a, b) {
                        return Date.parse(b.snippet.publishedAt) - Date.parse(a.snippet.publishedAt);
                    })

                    for (var i = 0; i < allVideos.length; i++) {
                        console.log(allVideos[i].snippet.title + " published at " + allVideos[i].snippet.publishedAt)
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        function GatherVideos(pageToken, finished) {
            var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
                part: 'snippet',
                playlistId: 'PLTK1i0pncVu_tLhgrPo_o7QcRocqozxUv',
                maxResults: 50,
                pageToken: pageToken
            });

            request.execute(function(response) {
                allVideos = allVideos.concat(response.items);
                if (!response.nextPageToken)
                    finished();
                else
                    GatherVideos(response.nextPageToken, finished);
            });
        }
    </script>

    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onGoogleLoad"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @theduck , I tried the code but returns a javascript error : "Can not read property 'setApiKey' of undefined" up into my comment the html code

Comment: OK - I have had another look at this code and tried to improve it. I have added paging functionality (YouTube API only returns max 50 videos which is a problem for your playlist). Hopefully, this should work OK for you now. Would be so much easier if they would add a `sort` option to the request!